# Showing the following collection is a $\sigma$-algebra of sets

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Let $X$ be any uncountable set. We show the following

$$ \mathscr{A} = \{ E \subset X : E \; \; \text{is countable or} \; \; E^c \; \; \text{is countable} \} $$

Suppose $E \in \mathscr{A} $, then we know $(E^c)^c $ is countable or $E^c$ is countable. In particular, $E^c \in \mathscr{A} $. Next, suppose $\{ E_n \} \subseteq \mathscr{A} $. If $E_n $ is countable for all $n$, then $E = \bigcup_{n \geq 1} E_n $is countable as well. If $E_n^c $ is countable for all $n$, then we have $ \bigcap_n E_n^c = \bigg( \bigcup_n E_n \bigg)^c $ is countable, and hence $\bigcup_n E_n \in \mathscr{A} $. We have shown that $\mathscr{A} $is a $\sigma$-algebra.

Is this a correct solution? Also, my concern is why do we need $X$ to be uncountable? it seems that I havent used this fact on my proof. In other words, can we just not assume that $X$ is uncountable?

Comment: What if some of the $E_n$ are countable, while others of the $E_n$ have countable complements?

Comment: What do you mean? I dont get it.

Comment: I mean that you have only included the cases where either all $A_n$ are countable, or all $A_n^c$ are countable. It is possible that you have a mix, where e.g. $A_1$ is countable, $A_2^c$ is countable, ...

Comment: $E$ is countable or $E^c$ is countable means that there may be the case that $E$ is not countable ? I still dont get it.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $\emptyset \in \mathscr{A}$

Your proof that $\mathscr{A} $ is closed under complementation is correct.

Let $\{ E_n \}_{n=1}^\infty\subseteq \mathscr{A}$. If $E_n$ is countable for all $n$, then, since the countable union of countable sets is countable, $\displaystyle\bigcup _{n=1}^\infty E_n$ is also countable and therefore $\displaystyle\bigcup_n E_n \in \mathscr{A}$.

Now, the negation of "$E_n$ is countable for all $n$" is "there exist $j$ such that $E_j$ is not countable". But, by hypothesis, $E_j \in \mathscr{A}$, and hence by the definition of $\mathscr{A}$ it must be that $(E_j) ^c$ is countable. But then: $$\left ( \bigcup _{n=1}^\infty E_n \right )^c=\bigcap _{n=1}^\infty \left ( E_n^c \right )\subseteq (E_j)^c$$

Since $(E_j)^c$ is countable, $\left ( \bigcup _{n=1}^\infty E_n \right )^c$ is also countable, and hence $\bigcup _{n=1}^\infty E_n\in \mathscr{A}$.

It follows that $\mathscr{A}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra.

The fact that $X$ is uncountable is probably there to make the question non-trivial. If $X$ were countable, all subsets of $X$ would also be countable and hence $\mathscr{A}=\mathcal{P}(X)$, so there's nothing to prove.